# Setting up Apache POI in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

How do I set up POI in IDEA?  I added

1. poi
2. poi-ooxml
3. poi-ooxml-schemas
4. xmlbeans

as dependencies. I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` caused by `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` as in

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/impl/CTPImpl$1BookmarkStartList
at
 org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTPImpl.getBookmarkStartList(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTPImpl$1BookmarkStartList
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 10 more

Comment: So...how are you setting them up as dependencies?

Comment: I copied the jars to a lib folder in the project, then right click -> Add as library

Comment: Which Class is not found? Please add the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

It  looks like you need the larger `ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar` (15MB), not just the `poi-ooxml-schemas.jar` (4mb). See here: http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/XWPF-CTP-Error-td4419509.html and here: http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025